# Statement has no effect and for loop

Tags: c, for-loop

So the purpose of this function is to kick certain numbers (that the user inputs) from array. For example if array is 3,3,4,5 and user wants to kick out 3, function should make array to be 4,5.
But when I try to compile I get following errors:

Line 1: No return, in function returning non-void 
Line 5: Statement has no effect 
Line 9: - Syntax error 
    - control reaches end of non-void function [- Wreturn-type]
    - expected declaration or statement at end of input

```
int izbaci_sve(int niz[], int vel, int p){
int i;
for (i = 0; i<vel; i++){
    if (niz[i] == p){
    for ( i; i+1<vel; i++)
        niz[i]=niz[i+1];
    vel = vel-1;}
return vel;
}
```

I don't know what's the problem with the first line when my function definitely returns an integer.

 For line 5 I want "for" loop to start from i that satisfies

```
niz[i] == p
```

And for line 9, I really don't know what kind of and syntax errors I have, it all looks legit to me.

Comment: Typo, you are missing ending `}` and move `return` one level down. Properly formatted code would probably have helped.

Comment: If you format your code properly then this kind of simple mistake becomes immediately apparent.

Comment: Yes, that solves syntax error.

Comment: Another nice example, how not identing properly does not help.

Comment: "for (i = 0; i+1 < vel; i++)"

Comment: that's why one should indent the code properly

Answer (score 2):

You missed a `}` in the function. And place the `return` statement outside of the `for` loop.